# Why does malloc allocate more memory spaces than I ask for?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, valgrind

I found that `malloc()` allocates more memory spaces than I ask for.

```
struct { void *ptr; int var; } msg;   // 16 bytes (checked by sizeof())

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    malloc(sizeof(msg));
```

As the aforementioned code, `malloc()` actually allocate 32 bytes per function call (calculated by `top`), but `valgrind` shows only 16 bytes per call indeed.

Why does malloc allocate more memory spaces than I ask for, and how to force `malloc()` not to waste that much memory spaces?

Surprisingly, it allocates 32 bytes **also** even if the struct is 24 bytes, so I guess that the memory spaces are wasted. I am not sure whether `malloc()` should allocate a multiple of 32 bytes. If it's true, than the memory spaces are wasted.

**EDITED:**

I've tested for other circumstances.

```
+---------+---------------------------+
|    n    | memory usage of malloc(n) |
+---------+---------------------------+
|  1 ~ 24 |         32 bytes          |
+---------+---------------------------+
| 25 ~ 40 |         48 bytes          |
+---------+---------------------------+
| 41 ~ 56 |         64 bytes          |
+---------+---------------------------+
```

The memory is not fully used if `n` is not `16 * m + 8`, `m` ∈ ℕ. Some memory spaces wasted are understandable because of memory alignment when `n` equals 22, but it still should be regarded as **wasted** when `n` equals 16. On most of the platforms, the size of minimum memory access unit is 4 bytes or 8 bytes, so why does GCC implementation choose 16 bytes per increase.

Comment: There is overhead per allocation. `malloc` needs some memory for its own data structures. See for example [Malloc vs custom allocator: Malloc has a lot of overhead. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064850/malloc-vs-custom-allocator-malloc-has-a-lot-of-overhead-why)

Comment: Surprisingly, it allocates 32 bytes **also** even if the struct is 24 bytes, so I guess that the memory spaces are **wasted**.

Comment: Why do you say it is wasted? Wasted implies a cost without anything in return which is not really the case here. It's the cost of managing the memory in a certain way.

Comment: It makes no sense that malloc allocates the same size of memory spaces if the size of struct is different because the extra overhead for maintenance should be the same.

Comment: You seem to be acting as an arm chair coder hollering from the side lines. And you have made a conclusion based on two data points without really understanding the issues being solved by the implementation. Feel free to write your own *general purpose* memory allocator that is super efficient and performs better than `malloc` in all cases. You'll quickly find out that it isn't that easy.

Comment: I agree with that, but I am trying to find the solution without writing my own memory allocator. If my problem cannot be solved easily, then I have to do that because of the low memory usage is the highest priority in this project.

Answer (score 1):

Any extra memory, if any, allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc. is an implementation defined aspect of the system and not specified by C.

Check your compiler's specification to determined why.   Usually it is for memory management.

To force a different allocation scheme, re-write `malloc()` or use your own memory allocation functions.

Answer (score 1):

**`malloc ()`** has very significant run-time **overheads**. The GNU C Library uses `ptmalloc` which is based on `dlmalloc` ("Doug Lea's Malloc").

Memory on the heap is allocated as "chunks", an `8-byte` aligned data structure which contains a header, and usable memory. Allocated memory contains an `8` or `16 byte` overhead for the size of the chunk and usage flags. Unallocated chunks also store pointers to other free chunks in the usable space area, making the minimum chunk size `24 bytes`.

Unallocated memory is grouped into "bins" of similar sizes, implemented by using a double-linked list of chunks (with pointers stored in the unallocated space inside the chunk).

For requests below `256 bytes` (a "smallbin" request), a simple **two power best fit allocator** is used. If there are no free blocks in that bin, a block from the next highest bin is split in two.

You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#dlmalloc)

Comment: Plus 1 for your great information, but this still cannot reduce the memory usage in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The excess bytes allocated i.e. the overhead is implementation specific, the memory manager in the implementation allocates as much memory as is necessary for internal tracking / house-keeping purposes. The memory space is not considered as being wasted. 
Your concern is genuine especially if you are looking at Millions of small allocations - this will lead to extensive heap memory fragmentation and of course the huge overhead. So I can think of two options - write your heap allocator or better use memory manager written/tested/shared by others - start with Facebook's [jemalloc](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919)  or  Google's [tcmalloc](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) -

Comment: I edited my question to explain the reason why I think the memory space is considered as being wasted.